# I want to make my mac to use gcc not clang

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

I'm using mac and tried to complile with gcc and this is my Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O -Wall -m32
LIBS = -lm

all: btest fshow ishow

btest: btest.c bits.c decl.c tests.c btest.h bits.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o btest bits.c btest.c decl.c tests.c

fshow: fshow.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o fshow fshow.c

ishow: ishow.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ishow ishow.c

# Forces a recompile. Used by the driver program.
btestexplicit:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o btest bits.c btest.c decl.c tests.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o btest fshow ishow *~
```

But it gives me like

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [btest] Error 1
```

I think it still uses "clang" not gcc.
I want to force my mac to use gcc.

I have seen other post but it does not resolve...

*It is the code from CSAPP datalab

Comment: what does this program does btw

Comment: By default `gcc` is just an alias for `clang`. Have you installed GCC anywhere? How about rearranging the `PATH` environment variable to put the GCC installation `bin` directory before the path where Clang is installed?

Comment: What command are you using to run the program

Comment: @HammadKhan It is datalab from CSAPP

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes i've already installed. How can I edit PATH environment variable "before the Clang path"? I cannot understand put PATH variable "before"

Comment: @HammadKhan I just used 'make' command

Comment: dont you use 'gcc program.c' command to run the program?

Comment: make the symbolic link point at the gcc binary instead of clang.

Comment: @klutt Thank you for your help but i don't know what is symbolic link... I'm just a beginner

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln

Comment: Did you install GCC? Did you use **homebrew** to install GCC?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes i solved my problem by using alias cc="gcc"